GEE COPERNICUS/S3/OLCI Qa10_radiance band provides inconsistent data range
I am tyring to compute OTCI - OLCI terrestrial chlorophyll index (custom-scripts.sentinel-hub.com/custom-scripts/sentinel-3/otci/) by using google earth engine 'COPERNICUS/S3/OLCI'dataset. There is no issue on computing the index for the study years 2019 and 2020-06-30.
Started from 2020-07-01 till 2023-12-31, the value range of Qa10_radiance became lager than the other two bands (Qa11_radiance and Qa12_radiance) which used in the index computation.
For example in the median composite of OLCI Image of (2023-01-01, 2023-06-30), Oa01_radiance of sentinel 3 olci sensor has value range from -2144206848 to 52953088. 2019 and first half of 2020 are not like that.
Below is the code I used in GEE.
What am I missing here?
var sentinel3 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S3/OLCI')
              .filterDate('2020-07-01', '2020-12-30')
              .filterBounds(roi);
var uniqueOrbits=[1,44,58,101,158,215,372];
uniqueOrbits.forEach(function(orbit) {
  var orbitCollection = sentinel3.filter(ee.Filter.eq('relative_orbit_num', orbit));
  Map.addLayer(orbitCollection.median().clip(roi), imageVisParam, 'Orbit ' + orbit);
});

var filter = ee.Filter.or(ee.Filter.eq('relative_orbit_num', 215),
                          ee.Filter.eq('relative_orbit_num', 372),ee.Filter.eq('relative_orbit_num', 1),
                          ee.Filter.eq('relative_orbit_num', 44),ee.Filter.eq('relative_orbit_num', 58),
                          ee.Filter.eq('relative_orbit_num', 101),
                          ee.Filter.eq('relative_orbit_num', 158));



  // filter the collection
var collection_orbit = sentinel3.filter(filter);

    var input_image= collection_orbit.select(['Oa10_radiance', 'Oa11_radiance', 'Oa12_radiance'])
              .median()
              .clip(roi)
              // Convert to radiance units.
              .multiply(ee.Image([0.00773378, 0.00675523, 0.0071996]));//apply band-specific scale factors.
Map.addLayer(input_image, {}, 'input_image');
              
// Select the required bands (B10, B11, and B12 correspond to bands 10, 11, and 12 of OLCI)
var B10 = rgb.select('Oa10_radiance');
var B11 = rgb.select('Oa11_radiance');
var B12 = rgb.select('Oa12_radiance');

// Calculate OTCI
var OTCI = B12.subtract(B11).divide(B11.subtract(B10));

print('OTCI');
print(OTCI);

// Define the color blend visualization function
var colorBlend = function(value, min, max, colors) {
  return value.visualize({
    min: min,
    max: max,
    palette: colors
  });
};

var min=OTCI.reduceRegion({reducer: ee.Reducer.min(), geometry: roi, scale: 30}).get('Oa10_radiance');
print('min');
print(min)

var max=OTCI.reduceRegion({reducer: ee.Reducer.max(), geometry: roi, scale: 30}).get('Oa10_radiance');
print('max');
print(max)
// Apply the color blend visualization
var OTCIVis = colorBlend(
  OTCI, 
  0, 
  5,  // Range of OTCI values for visualization
  ['#000080', '#004d99', '#ff3333', '#ffcc00', '#00cc66', '#009933', '#ffffff'] // Corresponding color palette
);

Map.setCenter(160.2143186037913,-9.599166499275967, 8);
Map.addLayer(OTCIVis, {}, 'OTCI');


If I am not mistaken OTCI is a Level 2 product, calculated from Surface reflectances, with atmospheric correction taken place already.
Since GEE features Level 1b top-of-atmosphere radiance data, I would doubt that your final results will be accurate, compared to the official OTCI product.
https://www.mdpi.com/2072-4292/12/16/2652
Check this article. Also, Level 2 OTCI product is available on Copernicus Data Space Ecosystem for downloadin
